# Possible to remember consumed orders?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an Android application using Google's in app billing v3. I have a donate button whereby users can donate if they would like to do so. Once a purchase is made I "consume" the order immediately so they could donate again in the future.

I would now like to detect users that have previously donated. Is this possible?

Comment: Save a record of each transaction including a way to identify the person who donated. When a donation occurs, check the records.

Comment: @worsnupd the donations have already occurred. Thanks!

Comment: @Flyview I wanted to add something similar to my app (donation using in app purchase), can you comment what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Just create a consumable in app purchase @NishantSingh

Comment: @Flyview great, thanks.